# Using .write() in Python only writes a single line

Tags: python, web-crawler, file-writing

So, as an assignment from Thenewboston, I'm trying to grab a block of code from his site and write it to a file. The code grabbing part works just fine, but the writing part doesn't work:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def crawler(url):
    source = requests.get(url)
    source_text = source.text
    soup_obj = BeautifulSoup(source_text, "html.parser")
    for code in soup_obj.find('code'):
        codes = str(code)
        final_code = codes.replace('<br/>', '').replace('Â', '')
        print(final_code)
        fx = open('crawler_code.txt', 'w')
        fx.write(final_code)
        fx.close()

crawler('https://thenewboston.com/forum/topic.php?id=1610')
```

Comment: whats the error you are getting, please mention in question itself by editing

Comment: Move `open` and `close` lines outside of the loop

Comment: Opening a file in `w` mode **erases the contents**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overwriting the file within the loop

Open the file for writing before you loop and write

```
with open('crawler_code.txt', 'w') as fx:
    for code in soup_obj.find('code'):
        codes = str(code)
        final_code = codes.replace('<br/>', '').replace('Â', '')
        print(final_code)
        fx.write(final_code)
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not really mentioned what was the issue, but I think as you open the file for each line you're grabbing (therefore erasing the content with `'w'` mode), you only have one line written in the file at the end. Is it your problem ?

If so, try to open the file before your loop, at the beginning of the crawl method.